# My Pytorch multi-GPU prediction code freezes at `spawn()`

Tags: python, pytorch, concurrency, multi-gpu

The following small code does multi-GPU prediction using Pytorch.

I launch multiple `task`s using `torch.multiprocessing.spawn()`.

Inside `task`, I put no real prediction code. Just putting something into a common `Queue` to collect prediction results.

This code prints `{rank} destroyed` well. All four processes have printed this message.

It then stuck here. The message `'Spawn end'` never shows up. This means `torch.multiprocessing.spawn()` never ends.

I put `try` codes in `task`, but no exception are thrown.

Please help me find this bug.

```
from typing import List
import torch
import torch.multiprocessing
import torch.distributed
import os
from torch.utils.data.dataloader import DataLoader
from torch.utils.data.distributed import DistributedSampler
from distributed_predictor import DistributedDataset

world_size = 4
batch_size = 16
data = [i for i in range(10000)]

class DistributedDataset(torch.utils.data.Dataset):
    def __init__(self, list:List):
        super(DistributedDataset, self).__init__()
        self.data = list
    def __getitem__(self, index):
        return self.data[index]
    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.data)

dataset = DistributedDataset(list=data)

def task(rank:int, result_queue:torch.multiprocessing.Queue):
    try:
        torch.distributed.init_process_group('nccl', rank=rank, world_size=world_size)
        torch.cuda.set_device(device=rank)
        sampler = DistributedSampler(dataset, num_replicas=world_size, rank=rank)
        dataloader = DataLoader(dataset, 
                                batch_size=batch_size, 
                                pin_memory=True, 
                                sampler=sampler, 
                                shuffle=False)
        process_result = []
        for batch in dataloader: 
            process_result.extend(batch)
        result_queue.put(process_result)
        torch.distributed.barrier()
        torch.distributed.destroy_process_group()
        print(f'{rank} destroyed')
    except:
        print('error')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    os.environ['MASTER_ADDR'] = 'localhost'
    os.environ['MASTER_PORT'] = '12356'     
    torch.multiprocessing.set_start_method('spawn', force=True)
    result_queue = torch.multiprocessing.Queue()        
    torch.multiprocessing.spawn(task, args=(result_queue,), nprocs=world_size)
    print(f'Spawn end')
    results = []
    for _ in range(world_size):
        results.append(result_queue.get())
```

Comment: I find the reason. I should add `join=True` in `torch.multiprocessing.spawn(task, args=(result_queue,), nprocs=world_size)`.